# How to echo text right-to-left in php?

Tags: php, css

Is there a way to echo text rtl in php?
I am doing css code direction mail protection with:

```
.safemail{
    direction: rtl;
    unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
}
```

For this to work i need mail to be echoed right-to-left

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `strrev`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php

Here's an example:

```
<?php
echo strrev("Hello world!"); // outputs "!dlrow olleH"
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

1 option is to reverse the string in php, as described by others. But for large text, this can be heavy for your server when handling large amount of text for many people.

An option is to use the following html chars

```
&#x202e; this text will be reversed as it is after the special char <br>
&#x202d; this text won't be reversed anymore
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sYafq/ --> proof of concept.

The first special char will reverse all the following text.

the second special will undo the effect for the following text. Notice that when you don't put the 
 tag the second sentence will appear before the first sentence.

if you have 1 chuck of text to reverse, you can use it as follows

```
not reversed text
<div>
    &#x202e; reversed text
</div>
not reversed text
```

Comment: @Yesian this is a better solution because it pushes the processing load out to the client.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the string-reverse function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php

```
<?php
echo strrev("mail@domain.com");
?>
```